# Swift: Change Type of View Controller to Something Other than UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm, relatively, a beginner, so this may be an entirely common practice—or an entirely impossible one—but I've been wondering if it's possible to modify a view controller added in a storyboard so that instead of (or in addition to?) being an instance of `UIViewConroller`, it's also an instance of `(blahblah)ViewController`, e.g. `ABUnknownPersonViewController`.

That way, instead of doing something like this:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let test = ABUnknownPersonViewController() 
        ...
        self.presentViewController(test, animated: false, completion: nil) 

    }

}
```

*This* could be done:

```
class ViewController : ABUnknownPersonViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() { 

         //ViewController already is an ABUnknownPersonViewController, so you can treat it as one 
         //example below (displayedPerson is a property of ABUnkownPersonViewControllers)
         self.displayedPerson...

    }

}
```

**EDIT:** `ABUnknownPersonViewController` is a class supplied by Apple, which does **not** support subclassing ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABUnknownPersonViewController_Class/index.html)). With that said, and the understanding that I would obviously like as simple a solution as possible (avoidance of protocols and whatnot), what are my options?

I tried `class FourthViewController: UIViewController, ABUnknownPersonViewController, ABUnknownPersonViewController, ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate` only to get an error about multiple inheritance.

Comment: What's is the problem of `ABUnknownPersonViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` and then `ViewController` inherit from `ABUnknownPersonViewController`, it's the purpose of inheritance

Comment: @VictorSigler `ABUnknownPersonViewController` cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Can you explain in a more general sense what you are trying to achieve? Is it that you want to customize the view of ABUnknownPersonViewController or something else?

Comment: Of course. I **don't** need to customize it, I just want it to be such that when I segue from another ViewController to this one, it's already an instance of an ABUPVC, so that I won't have to create one and present it.

Comment: In that case you don't even need to put it in the storyboard. The simplest thing to do is just to create one and push it onto your navigation stack in code. Note that the documentation says that it requires the use of a navigation controller.

Comment: I'll give that a try. What I've been doing is similar—segueing to the new VC, then immediately pushing the ABUPVC from there, which results in a slight lag where the user can see the new VC from which the ABUPVC is presented, but it seems like what you're suggesting is that I just push the ABUPVC from the class where the segue originates, and shove all of the functionality from the other VC into that one, which probably should have been obvious, even though the intermediary one does have a large amount of ancillary functions which I was trying to separate from the one where the segue begins.

Comment: If you would like to keep that code separate, consider keeping it in a separate class that is NOT a UIViewController. Your initial VC can just hold a reference to an instance of that class.

Comment: Excellent idea. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is to subclass UIViewController, and in your storyboard, set the custom class to your subclass. When the view controller is loaded from the storyboard, it will be an instance of your subclass.

So your subclass would look like this:

```
class ABUnknownPersonViewController : UIViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
         self.displayedPerson...

    }

}
```

In the storyboard, highlight the view controller you want to use a custom class for, and in the Custom Class field, type the name of your subclass. If you've done it correctly, it should autocomplete for you.

[image]

Comment: To be clear, ABUnknownPersonViewController is not a class of my creation, but rather a part of the AddressBookUI—provided by Apple, as a UITableView is, for example.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that since I'm not familiar with Address Book UI. In that case, what you actually want to subclass is ABUnknownPersonViewController as shown in Patrick Lynch's answer (not sure why it was down voted). ABUnknownPersonViewController is already a subclass of UIViewController so your subclass will still be a view controller. You can still set the view controller custom class in the storyboard as shown in the image.

Comment: Looks like you are looking at the ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate documentation rather than ABUnknownPersonViewController, which does show UIViewController in it's inheritance tree. However, subclassing it could still be a bad idea as there are some Apple-provided view controllers that do not support subclassing.

Comment: Completely right! However, please see the newly linked document, which does, in fact, specify that subclassing is not supported, as you suspected.